# Jquery animate navigation color

Tags: jquery, html, background-color, fade, nav

Hi I am making a website at the moment and am I having trouble with animating the navigation bar.

I would like the navigation bar to be transparent originally, than for it to change background-color after a certain div. I have done this but want the background-color to fade in, not just appear.
Below is the HTML and Jquery.

How do I make it fade to the background-color?

***HTML***

```
<div class="nav">
      <div class="container">
       <div class="logo">
       <a href="#"><img src="RepublicSquare_logo.svg" style="height: 80px;"></a>
       </div>
        <div class="navMain">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

***Jquery***

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#c-title');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'rgba(34,34,34,0.9)');
       } else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for taking the time to answer the question.
(I hope the question is clear, if not let me know)

Comment: Could you make a jsfiddle? => [JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: @user3218008 so everything here is accurately changing the `background-color`, but you want that change from `transparent` to `rgba(34,34,34,0.9)` to fade in?

Comment: @Godisgood yes that is correct. It's transparent to begin with, than once it reaches the #c-title by scrolling down the page it should fade into rgba(34,34,34,0.9)

Comment: @ethorn10, the above comment was actually for you.

Comment: @user3218008 if Mohamed-Yousef's solution worked, accept his answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code in your css

```
.nav{
    transition-duration: 2s;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq8mab34/1/)

Comment: That was just the heading element in which it would trigger to change color.

Comment: if your code already working .. just add transition-duration: 2s; to your .nav class

Comment: Stupid question but how do you do that?

Comment: The transition-duration property specifies how many seconds (s) or milliseconds (ms) a transition effect takes to complete. and in demo I assumed that you have a div in top and want to change nav bgcolor after the scroll hide this div..right? so I made my code if scroll after the height of the red div take action .. thats it

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>

  $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#c-title');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.nav').animate({background-color: rgba(34,34,34,0.9)}, 1000);
       } else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});
</script>
```

Comment: maybe try it now... without the qoute

Comment: no that didn't work. Do you know of any other options I could use?

Answer (score 1):

Try using JQuery's build in `animate()` function. Like so:

```
$('yourDiv').animate({"color" : "red"},500);
```

This will fade the color rather than just change it.

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. Do you mean like this:  $(document).ready(function(){       
   var scroll_start = 0;
   var startchange = $('#c-title');
   var offset = startchange.offset();
   $(document).scroll(function() { 
      scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
      if(scroll_start > offset.top) {
          $('.nav').animate({"color" : "red"},500);
       } else {
          $('.nav').css('background-color', 'transparent');
       }
   });
});

Comment: Yes, that will ensure the site is fully loaded before anything happens.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `fadeIn()` is not intended for this type of use. It fades in matching elements, not specific properties. As others have mentioned, you could use `animate()`, but from the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animation-properties), you'll see that `background-color` is not one of the properties unless a plugin is used:

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
>   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
>   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
>   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
>   [jQuery.Color()](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used)