# jQuery scroll function read when page scrolled at bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am working to make menu to change when users scrolling the page. It's working, but I have glitch that my code only working when I scrolled to the very bottom of page.

This is jQuery script :

```
var scroll_start = 0;
var startchange = $('#startchange');
var offset = startchange.offset();

$(window).scroll(function() { 
  scroll_start = $(this).scrollTop();
  if(scroll_start > 1) {
    $(".home .navbar-default").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $(".home .navbar-default").css('opacity', '0.8');
    $(".page-template-page-full-width-php .navbar-default").css('background-color', '#000000');
    $(".page-template-page-full-width-php .navbar-default").css('opacity', '0.8');
   } else {
    $('.home .navbar-default').css('background-color', 'transparent');
    $('.page-template-page-full-width-php .navbar-default').css('background-color', 'transparent');
   }
});
```

I was tried some codes including from this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27307633/jquery-animate-navigation-color). I modified the code, to looks just like my current code at above, but it's still only working when scrolled to the very bottom. This is my [website](http://f1.webmasons.sg/). Anyone know why the code only working when scrolled at bottom? I tried to read the parameter with `alert`, but the alert only showing when I reached the very bottom of page with 32 as the value.

Comment: Your `$(window).scroll` listener doesn't work. If you remove the `overflow-x:hidden` from the `html, body` selector it will work.

Comment: Thank you! It's working now. But, how can CSS code affected the script?

Comment: Because the `scroll` event related to the `overflow` property. If there is no `overflow` the `scroll` event will not fire. **Note:** In the future, if you want to nutify other user (like in this case) that you did something (you comment hin, for example) you need to add `@` and his username in your comment. [Read more about it](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: @MoshFeu - Thanks again! I got it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck..